# What are the step to integrate Paypal with Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, paypal

I have checked the Paypal documentation but everything is very confuse to me. Can somebody help me to get this clear.

I have created my sandbox account both (merchant and buyer) and I have upgraded the merchant sandbox account to Business Pro. Now I would like to use the Paypal REST API to integrate Paypal in my web application, which I am developing using Angularjs and ASP.NET Web Api.

I am not just looking for code, I am trying to figure out the step I need to do in my paypal account in order to be able to connect everything, once I have accomplished this.

Comment: have u tried https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout ?

Comment: @yesIcan, Do u know if I have to install something to be able to use this?

Comment: There is nothing to install. Just follow the instruction on that page.